# z-index, how does it affect performance?

Tags: css, performance, z-index

How does the css z-index value affect performance?

If I have multiple images on a page does it matter if I use high z-index values, like 10,000?

For example, a page contains 15 images with z-indexes ranging from 500 - 10,000, and if the images are moveable (jQuery draggable), does it impact upon performance by using high values if the page is redrawn so frequently?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The number of layers matters, but the actual value of the z-index does not.  When rendering the page, the browser just sorts all of the absolutely-positioned elements by their z-index (ascending) and draws them in that order.

EDIT:
Also, the performance hit from sorting only occurs when you *change* the z-index of the layers.  If the z-indices aren't changing often, the performance hit probably won't be noticeable at all.  Even if you are changing the z-indices a lot, sorting a list of 15 items is almost instantaneous.

Comment: Always wondered about this. Some plugins add values like 9999 to try and "always be on top" so when you want to override that you have to use numbers like 10000 or 99999 - good to know it doesn't matter what the numbers are for performance.

Answer (score 3):

While not a direct answer to the question of performance, an important additional consideration when talking about using very high z-index numbers:

> 2147483647 is the maximum z-index in most web browsers because
>   it's the largest possible 32-bit integer value. Any number higher than
>   2147483647 will automatically revert back to 2147483647.

From https://wordpress.org/support/topic/css-reference-to-the-tinymce-absolute-position-handle

Answer (score 1):

Yes. To what degree is difficult to answer without seeing the entire page, however some performance issues are at play.  With Z index manipulation and with jQuery and other libraries that select and manipulate DOMs dynamically you are basically restructuring the layout of HTML chunks.  Importantly a browser has no idea what MODAL means.  Any request to change layout essentially asks the browser to recalculate the DOM. That is your performance hit.